# Converted Rails 3.0.9 to Rails 3.1.1 and lost my stylesheets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Presumably my Javascript files are lost too...

I moved the stylesheets from public/ to app/assets/stylesheets (FYI did not find them in public/assets either).

Searching on the error confused me more...

> Error is ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
>   "/assets/application.css")

My routes for a pure Rails 3.1 app do not mention assets and yet it works fine.

Content of application.css

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
*/
```

Not sure what else I should put here other than I was following these directions (probably not well): [Upgrade Rails 3 to 3.1](http://webtempest.com/upgrade-rails-3-to-3-1/)

Comment: Worked only after I went to http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails 3.1 with the asset pipeline enabled, all assets (javascripts, css, and images) are accessible via the `assets` path in the browser and no longer via `javascripts` and `stylesheets` as before. This is because Rails manipulates your assets (compiles, bundles and minifies).

Be sure to watch the [Railscasts episode on the Asset Pipeline](http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline).

Comment: I guess you could say this helped as when I went to http://localhost:300/assets/application.css the file compiled and I was able to see them in the app afterward

Answer (score 0):

This railscasts might also be very useful to you.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1

Answer (score 0):

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-3-1#to

Here is another good resource for those that landed here looking for help migrating to 3.1. Michael Hartl goes through a step-by-step process upgrading an existing app to rails 3.1

This is where I found the answer when I had this exact issue a few weeks ago.